# Get all properties except static ones

Tags: php, reflection

I tried:

```
$rc = new \ReflectionClass($this);
$rc->getProperties(ReflectionProperty::IS_PUBLIC || ReflectionProperty::IS_PRIVATE || ReflectionProperty::IS_PROTECTED)
```

But all that did was give me the one `static` property that the class has. It has 3 `private` and one `static`. I just want to know how to weed out the `static` ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `static` properties are also `public`, `private` or `protected`, so it returns them as well.  You need to check each property with `isStatic()`:

```
foreach($rc->getProperties() as $prop) {
    if(!$prop->isStatic()) {  // or $prop->isStatic() === false
        $result[] = $prop;
    }
}
```

`getProperties()` defaults to all properties.